# how to remove duplicate numbers

Tags: c, arrays, duplicates

i need to remove duplicate numbers from a user array.
and i nedd to use a function like RemoveDup.
i have an eror: "expression must have pointer to object type"
i looked on the older forims and didnt succseed to solve the problem. can you help me plz?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma warning (disable: 4996)

void sortAsending(int arr[], int size);
void swap(int* a, int* b);
void RemoveDup(int, int);

void main()
{

    int arr[10];
    int i, size ;

    printf("please enter size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    printf("please enter %d numbers: ", size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    printf("the original array is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    sortAsending(arr, size);
    printf("the sorted array is: ");

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = temp;
}

void sortAsending(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = size - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j]>arr[j + 1])
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);
        }
    }
}
void RemoveDup(int arr, int size)
{
    int arr[size];
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < size;)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                for (k = j; k < size; k++)
                    arr[k] = arr[k++];
                size--;
            }
            else
                j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to start with, change your code [if compiler supports VLA] to `int i, size ;...scanf(size)...int arr[size];` or consider adding range check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//prototype
void RemoveDup(int arr[], int *size);

//Assumes that it is sorted
//call RemoveDup(arr, &size);//size is updated.
void RemoveDup(int arr[], int *size){
    int *d, *s, *endp = arr + *size;
    if(*size == 1)
        return;
    d = s = arr;
    while(++s != endp){
        if(*d != *s){
            *++d = *s;
        }
    }
    *size = d - arr + 1;
}
```

Comment: It seems like it is better to use the `qsort` to sort. Also, I think it can be remove duplicate in your sort If you make use of your sort. (If that is no need to separate the sorting) Whereby you can reduce the code.

Comment: thanks you all for the help. i tried what you suggested and its working! thanks alot. by the way is it simple to make the nonduplicated array to fill itself with random numbers for the last parts that missing after the filter?

Answer (score 1):

The `RemoveDup()` function has an argument `int arr` which should be `int *arr`. It also defines a local `int arr[size]` which should be removed.

Note that changes to `size` are not noticed by the caller, you must return the new size (or take a pointer to the caller's size).

Answer (score 0):

Your function is incorrectly declared. Instead of

```
void RemoveDup(int arr, int size);
```

there shall be

```
void RemoveDup( int *arr, int size);
```

or

```
void RemoveDup( int arr[], int size);
```

where these two declarations are equivalent and declare the same function.

Also instead of the original array passed to the function as an argument you are using a local array

```
void RemoveDup(int arr, int size)
{
    int arr[size];
```

And your function does not return to the caller information where there is the end of the array after removing duplicates.

I would write the function the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * RemoveDup( int *a, size_t n )
{
    int *p = a;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        int *q;

        while ( ++p != a + n && *p != *( p - 1 ) );

        q = p;

        while ( ++q != a + n )
        {
            if ( *q != *( p - 1 ) ) *p++ = *q;
        }
    }

    return p;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    int *q;

    int *p = RemoveDup( a, N );

    for ( q = a; q != p; ++q ) printf( " %d", *q );
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks you all
i used bluepixy solotion and it works just fine.by the way is it simple to make the nonduplicated array to fill itself with random numbers for the last parts that missing after the filter?

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma warning (disable: 4996)

void sortAsending(int arr[], int size);
void swap(int* a, int* b);
void RemoveDup(int arr[], int *size);

void main()
{

 int arr[10];
 int i, size ;
 
 printf("please enter size of array: ");
 scanf("%d", &size);

 printf("please enter %d numbers: ", size);
 for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
 printf("the original array is: ");
 for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  printf("%d ", arr[i]);
 printf("\n");

 sortAsending(arr, size);
 printf("the sorted array is: ");

 for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  printf("%d ", arr[i]);
 printf("\n");
 RemoveDup(arr, &size);
 printf("the nonduplicated array is: ");

 for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  printf("%d ", arr[i]);
 printf("\n");

}
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
 int temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}

void sortAsending(int arr[], int size)
{
 int i, j;
 for (i = size - 1; i > 0; i--)
 {
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
  {
   if (arr[j]>arr[j + 1])
    swap(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);
  }
 }
}
void RemoveDup(int arr[], int *size)
{
 int *d,*s,*endp=arr+ *size;
 if (*size == 1)
  return;
 d = s = arr;
 while (++s != endp)
 {
  if (*d != *s)
  {
   *++d = *s;
  }
  *size = d - arr + 1;
 }
}
```